# Working with backpropagation algorithm using softmax function in the neural network

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, neural-network, backpropagation

I am creating a Neural Network from scratch for MNIST data, so I have 10 classes in the output layer. I need to perform backpropagation and for that, I need to calculate `dA*dZ` for the last layer where `dA` is the derivative of the loss function `L` wrt the softmax activation function `A` and `dZ` is the derivative of the softmax activation function`A` wrt to `z` where `z=wx+b`. The size obtained for `dA` is `10*1` whereas the size obtained for `dZ` is `10*10`.

Is it correct? If yes, who do I multiply `dA*dZ` as they have different dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. However, you need to transpose `dA`, e.g. with `numpy.transpose(dA)`.
Then you will have the right dimensions of `dA` and `dZ` to perform matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks btw is it the correct way to apply the softmax the softmax derivative?

Comment: Yes, it's right, but don't forget to multiply by the derivative of `z` with respect to `w`.
Following link might be helpful for you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235528/backpropagation-with-softmax-cross-entropy